# compare 2 columns from 2 different csv files

Tags: shell, csv, awk

My intention is to compare a particular column of 2 different csv files & get the data from second file what is not there in first file. For example.

### First File

```
"siddhartha",1
"mukherjee",2
```

### Second file

```
"siddhartha",1
"mukherjee",2
"unique",3
```

### Expected output

```
"unique",3
```

The below command is working properly when the text size of the first column is limited, so in the above example its working.

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a);' file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

but is the text size of the 1st column is quite large (for example 10000 char), its not working. its cutting the text at a certain point.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Hash the text (your $1) ? But I'm unsure this will resolve the problem at all.

Comment: wrt `its not working. its cutting the text at a certain point.` - awk does not do that so if you are encountering a problem then something else is happening. You are asking for help to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the `comm` command?

something like this: `comm -23 file2.csv file1.csv`

Please read about it on `man comm`; and both files should be sorted before.

You can user `sort` to do that

Comment: This is a nice solution but what is the way to sort based on 1st column which has space & new line char? example.
"mukherjee 
Siddhartha ",2
"tes 
unique",3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below `awk`

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=","};FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2
 "unique",3
```

or

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2
"unique",3
```

Set the field separator to comma and read each `$1` value into a key

Comment: That's the same script the OP posted in his question and says isn't working for him. No point posting it again as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the post and the OP's comment which looks to be the issue thats the problem, but its unclear. Thank you :).